# LF Low-pass filter for RF

Tags: rf

I need to measure the RMS power in a DC-10KHz range of a signal that contains RF frequencies (up to 1GHz).

My idea was to design a low-pass filter with 10KHz cut-off frequency, and then measure the RMS power by sampling with a MCU or using some trueRMS chip.

But if I just design a low-pass filter with capacitors and coils, that will give me 10KHz cutoff frequency, I fear that the RF frequencies will just cripple through the coils and capacitors. Since these components is gonna have relative large values.

How do I measure the LF signal RMS power?

EDIT: I'm an electronics engineer, but I have only worked with digital and analog design, never with RF design. But finding the field interesting, I wanted to do a project mainly to get better RF design skills. So I decided to build a simple spectrum analyzer, using a PLL with integrated VCO, a mixer and some matching circuits. The PLL(VCO) generates the LO signal for the mixer, and by filtering the IF output signal and measuring the power from DC to some frequency, I should be able to get the frequency content at the LO frequency.

So this is why I need to filter the IF signal, since I want to know for which bandwidth the power is measured.

Hope that makes any sense...

Comment: This is a good question but needs more detail. 

What is the lowest frequency of unwanted signals? Separating 1 GHz signals from <= 10 kHz is 'trivially easy" [tm]. Even 1 Mhz is easy. 100 KhZ needs more care.

Describing your actual application in more detail will help us answer you better.

Comment: @Russel McMahon filtering 1Ghz content isn't trivially easy.  Package and implementation(PCB) parasitic effects are significant at those frequencies.  Building a functional RLC style filter for such frequencies out of through-hole components in a pregboard isn't trivial and near impossible in a breadboard.  To do it effectively you need small package sized surface mount components (0402 likely) on a printed PCB, which is far from trivial for many whom ask questions here.

Comment: All that ;-). That's in part is what the [tm] implies. ie the actual filter edge is so many decades away from the stated out of band signal that a single pole would be fine. I had visions of tinplate boxes or pcb construction but as this is gross out of band rejection of GHz signals it's nowhere near as hard as say a 100 Mhz/1 Ghz filter. ie it's not really "filtering 1 GHz content in the sense usually implied by that but OOB rejecting it. 5 decades away.

Comment: @Mark, I could make a PCB Low pass filter for 1GHz in hours that would work. No components required. I think just needing to filter 1GHz is trivially easy *when* compared to filtering signals from 11kHz to 1GHz, all with significant power.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a screened enclosure with a central screened partition and feedthrough capacitors connecting the 'dirty' side to the 'clean' side. You can get feedthrough capacitors with integrated ferrite beads but it all depends on your required attenuation.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore HF coupling all over the circuit, if you know that one particular spot in cicruit is immune. Build a fully closed calorimetric metal box/chamber (2-3 cm side) with single feedthrough cap, and load it with ordinary filter and thermistor. After this calibrate the thermistor using known sources and second identical thermistor for ambient.

You will have the lowest parts count true RMS calibrated sensor. If you need higher precision (few tens/hundreds ppm) then you can employ the air-flow, oil-immersed bath, bath in vacuum, thermocouples, platinum black bodies etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I have asked the question again, since I think my question was a bit off the target.